# choose between one of two programs in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a (bash) script I would like to run on two different computers, one is OpenBSD with the program `sha256`, the other is Ubuntu with `sha256sum`. What is the best/standard practice to allow the script to handle both cases?

Note that for `sha256` vs `sha256sum`, the other options into the program wouldn't need to be change, but for a different choice of programs, such as `wget` vs. `curl`, the other parameters would change too (e.g. `wget` vs. `curl -O`). Therefore, the best answer would allow different command line parameters as well depending on which program is available.

One way of fixing the program is to use a variable that changes depending on the exit status of `command`, `hash`, or `type`, as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

e.g.

```
SHA_PROGRAM=sha256
command -v "$SHA_PROGRAM"
# If the exit status of command is nonzero, try something else 
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    command -v "sha256sum"
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        printf "This program requires a sha256 hashing program, please install one\n" 1>&2
        exit 1
    else
        SHA_PROGRAM=sha256sum
    fi 
fi
$SHA_PROGRAM $MYFILE
```

But, that way seems a little verbose to me, not to mention the nested if-statement issue.

It could be generalized a bit by using an array of possible commands:

```
declare -a POSSIBLE_COMMANDS=("sha256" "sha256sum")
SHA_PROGRAM=""
for $OPT in "${POSSIBLE_COMMANDS[@]}"
do
    command -v "$OPT"
    # if the exit status of command is zero, set the command variable and exit the loop
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        SHA_PROGRAM=$OPT
        break
    fi
done 

# if the variable is still empty, exit with an error    
if [ -z "$SHA_PROGRAM" ]; then
    printf "This program requires a sha256 program. Aborting\n" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

$SHA_PROGRAM $MY_FILE
```

That way would work too I believe, but I am hoping to get advice from a more experienced, better bash programmer, in case I am missing some better solution (perhaps a clever use of the `||` operator?).

Comment: If both platforms have `openssl` installed, you can just use `openssl sha256` in both places and not worry about picking an os-specific program.

Comment: I realized after writing this question, this question may be better suited for stack overflow. Should I move it?

Comment: `openssl sha256` looks good for generating the hash. Is there a related way to check a file with the hashes listed in it. I.e. equivalent to `sha256 -c FILE`?

Comment: I don't believe openssl provides such an option.

Comment: `for $OPT in ...` won't work, remove `$`.  And it's superfluous to use `$?` just for checking success/failure, simply write `if command -v "$OPT"; then`.

Comment: does OpenBSD have the `uname` command? If so you could use this output and check which system you are working on at the very beginning: `if [ "$(uname -a)" == "Linux" ] ; then linux=true ; else linux=false ; fi`. Or a `case` selection for defining the OS. Note that since BASH does not have boolean variables, future checks must be `if [ "$linux" == "true" ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @yaegashi's comment, the `if command -v ...; then ...` seems to hit the nail on the head, simple and clear.

Example:

```
# The SHA_CMD variable can be used to store the appropriate command for later use
SHA_CMD=""
if command -v sha256; then
    SHA_CMD=sha256
elif command -v sha256sum; then 
    SHA_CMD=sha256sum
else 
    printf "This program requires a a sha256 program installed\n" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi 
"$SHA_CMD" "$MY_FILE" > "$MY_FILE.sha"
# Note: if any of the possible sha commands had command line parameters, then the quotes need to be removed from around $SHA_CMD
```